# Table with vertical borders along certain lines

Tags: tables

In my table, I would like vertical borders to appear on some rows but not all.
For example :
[image: results]

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {|ccc|}, hline{2,3}, vline{2,3} = {2}{solid},
}
  0 & 1 & 2 \\
  3 & 4 & 5 \\
  6 & 7 & 8
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For example (`\multicolumn{1}{column}{text}` locally changes the behaviour of a cell):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|ccc|}
0&1&2\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{4}&5\\
\hline
6&7&8
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[vlines]
\Block{1-3}{}  
0 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
  3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
\Block{1-3}{}
  6 & 7 & 8
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]